# Ignoring mypy no-redef error for temp variables

Tags: mypy

I use name "temp_*" for temperary variables, and since they are temperary, I often redefine them.

For example,

```
temp_result: int = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    temp_result += i
print(temp_result)

temp_result: float = 1.1
for i in range(1, 10):
    temp_result *= i
print(temp_result)
```

so when I execute mypy, it pops up errors like

```
mypy.ini: No [mypy] section in config file
mini_test.py:6: error: Name "temp_result" already defined on line 1  [no-redef]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So currently, I have to put "# type: ignore" manually every time I defined a temperary variable as below.

```
temp_result: int = 0  # type: ignore
for i in range(1, 10):
    temp_result += i
print(temp_result)

temp_result: float = 1.1  # type: ignore
for i in range(1, 10):
    temp_result *= i
print(temp_result)
```

I would like to know a way to allow redefinition of temporary variable(variable named "temp_*"),
but still doesn't allow redefinition of other variables.

```
# this is OK
temp_result: int = 0
temp_result: float = 1.1  

# this is not OK
result: int = 0
result: float = 1.1
```

**Is there a way to ignore all mypy error due to variable named "temp_*"** such as changing mypy.ini file?

Or **is there a better way of defining temperary variables**?

Comment: The error message isn't very clear. What it means is that you shouldn't provide the **type annotation** twice. Remove the `: int` from the second `temp_width` and you'll be fine. If you actually want to declare a different type, you should set [`allow_redefinition = True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-allow-redefinition) in your mypy config file.

Comment: @dROOOze Thank you for your comment. I added more explanation.

I know that an error will not occur if I do not initially add a type annotation to the temporary variable. However, I am currently looking for a way to easily determine the type of the temporary variable as in the example of 'temp_result,' so I am exploring ways to add type annotations to temporary variables.

Is there a way to allow redefinition for variables starting with 'temp_' but not for those that do not as default?